# Daily hard freezes (Ubuntu 21.10, Xubuntu, HP Spectre x360)

Tags: xubuntu, freeze

So this HP Spectre is freezing every day, sometimes after only 20 minutes of uptime, this is very frustrating :(

It freezes so completely it does not respond to any input, not even ctrl-alt-F1 or the REISUB trick. If I'm SSHing in from another computer when it freezes, the terminal stops updating and eventually connection drops.

How can I debug and if possible fix this? How does having to power off with the power button so often affect it? Supposedly not a good thing to do..

Some details from about screen:

- Ubuntu 21.10
- Xfce 4.16
- Intel Core i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60 GHz x 8.
- Memory 7.4 G
- GPU Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (3.0 G)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please [edit] your question to add information, comments are an Us to You channel, used to help you make your question better, and more likely to receive an appropriate answer.

Comment: Look at the last log entries of the previous boot (the one that froze) with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. How's your fan? How dusty is your computer? Some CPU overheats don't make it to the logfile.

Comment: thanks for commenting @waltinator - to look at the last log, does this still work after booting to the GUI and starting the terminal there or do I have to boot only the shell?

Comment: I'll buy a box of air tomorrow and de-dust the fan a bit, good tip..

Comment: Might it freeze completely if it runs out of both swap memory and RAM?